# Getting error in Procedure Call from Java Code

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g, jdbctemplate

A) Getting This Error :

> " PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRC_ST_PSB_BNK_REF_GEN'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored "

1) JAva Code

```
SqlParameterSource inParameters =
                    new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("IN_BATCHRUNID", Long.valueOf(this.batchRunId));

            this.jdbcCall =
                    new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("PRC_ST_PSB_BNK_REF_GEN").declareParameters(new SqlParameter[]
                    { new SqlOutParameter("OUT_REFCURSOR", -10, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(NetBankReconDTO.class)) });

            this.recuMap = this.jdbcCall.execute(inParameters);
```

2) Procedure

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE "PRC_ST_CSB_REF_GEN" 
(
IN_BATCHRUNID  NUMBER,
OUT_REFCURSOR  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
OUT_TOTREC     OUT NUMBER,
OUT_SUCCREC    OUT NUMBER,
OUT_FAILEREC   OUT NUMBER,
OUT_STATUSCODE OUT NUMBER,
OUT_STATUSDESC OUT VARCHAR2,
OUT_TOTALAMT   OUT NUMBER,
OUT_TOTALREC   OUT NUMBER
) 
AS

LV_NETBANKID NUMBER;
LV_CNT NUMBER;
LV_AMT NUMBER(18,2);
LV_NTRP_STATUS NUMBER;

BEGIN

  SELECT NETBANKID INTO LV_NETBANKID FROM  VTSTBATCHPRCSTRN WHERE BATCHRUNID=IN_BATCHRUNID;

  UPDATE VTSTREFVOIDREQ RREQ SET  REFVOIDBATCHRUNID=IN_BATCHRUNID,CURRSTATUSCODE='A'
  WHERE REFVOIDFLAG='V' AND CURRSTATUSCODE='I'  AND
        EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM VTSTAUTHZTRN AUTH WHERE AUTH.TRNREFNO = RREQ.TRNREFNO AND
                  AUTH.NETBANKID=LV_NETBANKID );

  UPDATE VTSTSETTLEREQ SET NBREFBATCHRUNID=IN_BATCHRUNID, CURRSTATUSCODE=6040,CURRSTATUSDESC='Sent to NetBank for Refund'
  WHERE NETBANKID=LV_NETBANKID  AND CURRSTATUSCODE=6020 AND SETTLETYPE='R';


    /* Update NTRP's transaction table */
   LV_NTRP_STATUS := FN_NTRP_REFUND_UPDATE(IN_BATCHRUNID); 


   /* Tot Count And Tot Amount */

  SELECT COUNT(1) , NVL(SUM(RREQ.REQAMT),0) INTO LV_CNT, LV_AMT
  FROM VTSTREFVOIDREQ RREQ
  INNER JOIN VTSTAUTHZTRN AUTH ON AUTH.TRNREFNO = RREQ.TRNREFNO
  INNER JOIN CGCMN.VTMESTR STR ON STR.STOREID = AUTH.STOREID
  WHERE REFVOIDBATCHRUNID=IN_BATCHRUNID ;



  SELECT COUNT(1)+LV_CNT, NVL(SUM(SREQ.SETTLEAMT),0)+LV_AMT INTO LV_CNT, LV_AMT
  FROM VTSTSETTLEREQ SREQ
  INNER JOIN VTSTAUTHZTRN AUTH ON AUTH.TRNREFNO = SREQ.TRNREFNO
  INNER JOIN CGCMN.VTMESTR STR ON STR.STOREID = AUTH.STOREID
  WHERE SREQ.NBREFBATCHRUNID=IN_BATCHRUNID AND SREQ.NETBANKID=LV_NETBANKID  AND SREQ.CURRSTATUSCODE=6040;


  OPEN OUT_REFCURSOR for
  SELECT
            AUTH.TRNREFNO AS OTHPARAMETER,
           'CSB' AS BANKNAME,
           'WORLDLINE' AS MEBUSSNAME,
           TO_CHAR(AUTH.HOSTTRNDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') AS TRNDATE,
           TO_CHAR(RREQ.REFUNDREQDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') AS REFDATE,
           NET.NETBANKMEID AS PAYEEID,
           AUTH.RRN AS BANKREFNO,
           AUTH.TRNREFNO AS TRNREFNO,
           AUTH.TOTTRNAMT AS TRNAMT,
           RREQ.REQAMT AS REFAMT
           FROM VTSTREFVOIDREQ RREQ
          INNER JOIN VTSTAUTHZTRN AUTH ON AUTH.TRNREFNO = RREQ.TRNREFNO
          INNER JOIN VTSMNETBNK NET ON AUTH.NETBANKID=NET.NETBANKID
          INNER JOIN CGCMN.VTMESTR STR ON STR.STOREID = AUTH.STOREID WHERE REFVOIDBATCHRUNID=IN_BATCHRUNID

   UNION ALL

  SELECT
           AUTH.TRNREFNO AS OTHPARAMETER,
           'CSB' AS BANKNAME,
           'WORLDLINE' AS MEBUSSNAME,
           TO_CHAR(AUTH.HOSTTRNDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') AS TRNDATE,
           TO_CHAR(SREQ.SETTLEREQDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') AS REFDATE,
           NET.NETBANKMEID AS PAYEEID,
           AUTH.RRN AS BANKREFNO,
           AUTH.TRNREFNO AS TRNREFNO,
           AUTH.TOTTRNAMT AS TRNAMT,
           SREQ.SETTLEAMT AS REFAMT
           FROM VTSTSETTLEREQ SREQ
           INNER JOIN VTSTAUTHZTRN AUTH ON AUTH.TRNREFNO = SREQ.TRNREFNO
           INNER JOIN VTSMNETBNK NET ON AUTH.NETBANKID=NET.NETBANKID
           INNER JOIN CGCMN.VTMESTR STR ON STR.STOREID = AUTH.STOREID
           WHERE SREQ.NBREFBATCHRUNID=IN_BATCHRUNID AND SREQ.NETBANKID=LV_NETBANKID AND SREQ.CURRSTATUSCODE=6040;

    /* Refund Response Ledger Posting  */
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO LV_CNT FROM VTSTSETTLEREQ SREQ
    INNER JOIN VTSMLVVEHICLE LV ON LV.LVID=SREQ.LVID AND LV.LVTYPE='A'
    WHERE NBREFBATCHRUNID=IN_BATCHRUNID AND SETTLETYPE='R' ;
      IF LV_CNT > 0 THEN
      BEGIN
        PRC_LED_NB_REF_FILERESP( IN_BATCHRUNID, 'SYSTEM','SYSTEM',OUT_STATUSCODE,OUT_STATUSDESC);
      END;
      END IF;


    OUT_SUCCREC:=LV_CNT;
    OUT_FAILEREC:=0;
    OUT_STATUSCODE:=0;
    OUT_STATUSDESC:='SUCCESS';
    OUT_TOTALAMT:=LV_AMT;
    OUT_TOTALREC:=LV_CNT;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
      OUT_STATUSCODE := 1;
      OUT_STATUSDESC := 'No Data Found';
    END;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
      OUT_STATUSCODE := 1;
      OUT_STATUSDESC := SQLERRM;
    END;

  END PRC_ST_CSB_REF_GEN;
```

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRC_ST_PSB_BNK_REF_GEN'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Please provide sample data input and output.

Comment: @DarkRob : only one input "IN_BATCHRUNID"  (123456) and out is cursor 
--
{ new SqlOutParameter("OUT_REFCURSOR", -10, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(NetBankReconDTO.class)) });

Comment: Your procedure has more than one out parameters; you need to set variables to hold the values returned by all the out parameters, not just one of them.

Comment: @Boneist - could you please make that an answer? Thanks.